# stop reload of entire page with .click & .load event

Tags: jquery

I have a simple site with a jumbo banner at the top, underneath this I have a navbar (bootstrap 4).  I am using this code to load different pages into the index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pageLoad").load("home.php");

    $(".nav-link").click(function() {
        $("#pageLoad").load($(this).attr("id") + ".php");
    });
});
```

If I scroll down the page a little but the navbar is still in view, and I click a link, it seems to refresh the page and go back to the top again.  It does load the correct link into the `<div>`  Is there a way of stopping this.

New to Stackoverflow, so excuse any things I have missed.  I have searched through a fair few articles, but can't find anything that helps with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not necessarily refresh the page, unless you have an empty href="" value. Replace the href value with this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

Also a e.preventDefault() call in your eventlistener function might help.

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#pageLoad").load($(this).attr("id") + ".php");
});
```

Comment: Great thanks!! Worked a treat.  Now just trying to work out why the "Brand" in the navbar does not work like the other links.  It will not load a page, I have set it up just like the other `<a>`.

Comment: Fixed this.  Didn't have the right class on the brand link!!